# iozone what is record size/record lengh?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, disk, iozone

We have build windows file server and i wan to run iozone to test Disk I/O performance so what kind of test i should run and how do i know how much i/o i will get at X size of file? also what is `record size` or `record lengh` I came across many time this word while i was googling..

I am running following test right now but i don't know how do i read stats and what that result meas.

```
iozone -R -r 1M -s 100m

                                                    random  random    bkwd   record   stride
      KB  reclen   write rewrite    read    reread    read   write    read  rewrite     read   fwrite frewrite   fre
  102400    1024 1438781 1833689  1647187  1731045 1770870 1881794 1933970  4323897  1973719  1954304  1743602 10781
```

Comment: Not a programming question, this is only about building and measuring computers.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure so i post here :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, IOzone benchmarks a file system by breaking up a file of a given size into records.
These records are written (or read) in a different way, according to the given test, until the file size is reached.

For example, your command (iozone -R -r 1M -s 100m) asks IOzone to execute all its tests (e.g. read, re-read, write, re-write, etc) over a file of 100MB. Read/Write operations are split into records of 1MB. It means that 100 operations are done over records of 1MB to achieve the tests.

Have a look at the results. The first number is the size of the file. The second is the record length. Then, numbers correspond to the throughput recorded for the different tests. Some tests are done several time (e.g. read, write, etc). First time is done sequentially, second time is done by random location accessing.

The following [document](http://www.iozone.org/docs/IOzone_msword_98.pdf) explains in details IOzone. Have a look at the description of the tests to understand their meanings.

Comment: What if record size (-r) is greater than block size of disk?